# How can I check if a number is registered in iMessage or not?

Tags: applescript, imessage

I'm looking for a way to find out that if a number has registered in iMessage or not. So far I know how to send a message using this script:

```
set number to "+111111111111"
set message to "Test"
tell application "Messages"
    set targetServise to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
    set targetBuddy to buddy number of targetService
    delay 1
    if targetBuddy exists then
        send message to targetBuddy
    end if
    #delay 5
end tell
```

All I need now, is to know whether this number has been registered in iMessage or not?

P.S: Is there any kind of API for that?

Comment: As far as I am aware, AppleScript can only send a message to someone you have previously sent messages to in  _Messages.app_ on macOS or in iOS; you cannot start a new conversation with a new number, even if that person already exists in your contacts.  Therefore, the question has no real world context to apply it to.  But as a point of curiosity, no, there is not public official API (but you may be able to Google a non-official API authored by others, but I doubt it would be tailored for AppleScript).

Comment: Thanks for your response. AppleScript just was a suggestion. I mean, if there are other options, I gladly will accept them. @CJK

Answer (score 0):

Your script will work correctly if you use, for example, **phoneNumber** instead of the **number** variable. And that's because the **number** keyword is reserved in the AppleScript language to denote the abstract class "number". Just don't use it and you will get what you are looking for.

Simple handler to check if the buddy (of service iMessage) with indicated phone number exists:

```
on buddyExists(phoneNumber)
    tell application "Messages"
        set targetBuddy to buddy phoneNumber of (1st service whose service type = iMessage)
        targetBuddy exists
    end tell
end buddyExists

buddyExists("+111111111111")
```